# It there a Generalised Wick theorem for rectangular matrices?

Tags: wick-theorem

Say we have several rectangular matrices (J,K) of different shapes, and we want to evaluate the Expected value, or Trace, of their Product

$$
\mathbb{E}[J_{1}^{T}J_{2}^{T}J_{3}^{T}K_{3}K_{2}K_{1}]
$$

Where the matrices are real but of different shapes, and non-random

Is there a way to express this using a Generalization of Wick's theorem (or Isserlis' theorem), to give

$$
\mathbb{E}[J_{1}^{T}K_{1}]\times\mathbb{E}[J_{2}^{T}K_{2}]\times\mathbb{E}[J_{3}^{T}K_{3}]+\cdots
$$

Comment: What are the sizes of the matrices?

Comment: I think this belongs more on [math.se], even if there's a (implicit, in the post) physical context.

Comment: The context is a problem in the statistical physics of neural networks. So, no, it belongs here.  But I can try asking there as well.

Comment: The size is of order 100x1000 or 1000x10000